# What is the NASA "free flying infrared sensor" that BBC News is referring to?

Tags: nasa, earth-observation

From [Obama seeks to raise NASA Funding (BBC News)](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-31113216):

> Nasa also wants to launch a free-flying infrared sensor to support the Landsat observations.

What is this "free-flying infrared sensor" they are referring to?  I'm not sure what "free flying" means in the context of satellites, if anything.

Answer (score 5):

Free-flying means the IR sensor will be carried by a dedicated satellite, as opposed to being added to an existing satellite. 
From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landsat_8):

> In August 2004, a memorandum from the White House Office of Science
>   and Technology Policy (OSTP) directed Federal agencies to place
>   Landsat-type sensors on the National Polar-orbiting Operational
>   Environmental Satellite System (NPOESS) platform.

That plan has been scuttled in favor of building a new Landsat 8 satellite specifically for the Landsat mission. This became operational in 2013. 
For Landsat 9 [a similar discussion has been taking place](http://spacenews.com/35116despite-past-failures-nasa-again-pursuing-landsat-alternative/), and the news article indicates that NASA again prefers to have a dedicated satellite.